# EvaluateException was unhandled by user code Cannot find column [year]

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i was trying to filter datagridview with a use of a combobox that is populated by values from a database
i'm having below error

> EvaluateException was unhandled by user code
>   Cannot find column [year].

here is my code

```
     Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class ReportTeacher
Dim MySqlConnection As MySqlConnection
Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable

    Private Sub ReportTeacher_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
    MySqlConnection.ConnectionString = "server = localhost; port=3307; user id = root; password = 1234; database = mcs;"

    Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter

    Dim bSource As New BindingSource


    Try
        MySqlConnection.Open()
        Dim query As String
        query = "SELECT DISTINCT year FROM mcs.year "
        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(query, MySqlConnection)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "mcs.year")

        With cmbxyear
            .DataSource = ds.Tables("mcs.year")

            .DisplayMember = "year"

            .ValueMember = "year"

        End With

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MySqlConnection.Dispose()

    End Try


    Try
        MySqlConnection.Open()
        Dim query As String
        query = "select * from mcs.faculties "
        Dim Command As New MySqlCommand(query, MySqlConnection)
        SDA.SelectCommand = Command
        SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
        bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource
        SDA.Update(dbDataSet)

        MySqlConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MySqlConnection.Dispose()

    End Try
End Sub

     Private Sub cmbxyear_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbxyear.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim DV As New DataView(dbDataSet)
    DV.RowFilter = String.Format(" year like '%{0}%' ", cmbxyear.SelectedItem)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = DV
End Sub
```

can you help me???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is just the position where you will call the values in mcs. year...it is after when you called the values of mcs.student and insert it into datagrid